# Auto resize child div to fill available space of parent div

Tags: html, css

I have two child divs inside a parent div. The first child div is 32% of the width, and the second child div is 68% of the width. If the first child div is set to `display: none;`, how do I make it so that the second child div goes from 68% of the width to 100% of the width? Thanks

```css
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

.child1 {
    width: 32%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}

.child2 {
    width: 68%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child1'></div>
  <div class='child2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend you use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) instead of floats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would leverage the magic of [flex](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)!

`flex: 0 0 32%;` On **child1** sets the width to 32%.

`flex: 1;` to the **child2** means: Fill all the available space. So if the child1 disappears, child 2 will fill all the remaining space.

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.child1 {
  flex: 0 0 32%;
  background-color: green;
}

.child2 {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child1'></div>
  <div class='child2'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) instead of float, setting `display: none` on one will adapt the other for you:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  document.querySelector('.child1').classList.toggle('hidden');
})
```

```css
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
}

.child1 {
    flex: 0 0 32%;
    background-color: green;
}

.child2 {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

button {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<button>Toggle child1 visibility</button>

<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child1'></div>
  <div class='child2'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Damn I just posted the exact same answer :D I'll go back to my beer & read about race conditions. Take my upvote & cheers

Answer (score 1):

Here instead of using float property you can use Flexbox. for more understanding follow this [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

so in flexbox you can achieve it by following the below code :-

```css
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
}

.child1 {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    flex:1;
}

.child2 {
   // display:none;
    height: 100%;
    flex:2;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  <div class='child1'></div>
  <div class='child2'></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

here's how you can achieve that using your approach.

```
  <div class="parent">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>

.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: white;
  }

  .child1 {
    width: 32%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
  }

  .child2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
  }
```